# Why is the package missing 'AudioEncoding'?

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client, google-text-to-speech, google-cloud-php-client

I'm trying to create an Text To Speech service which uses Google API Text-To-Speech.
Hee is my code:

```
// Setup Google Client
require_once '../../plugins/php/google-api-php-client-2.4.1/vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('../../plugins/php/google-api-php-client-2.4.1/credentials.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Texttospeech::CLOUD_PLATFORM);
$service = new Google_Service_Texttospeech($client);

// Setup Request
$input = new Google_Service_Texttospeech_SynthesisInput();
$input->setText('Japan\'s national soccer team won against Colombia!');

$voice = new Google_Service_Texttospeech_VoiceSelectionParams();
$voice->setLanguageCode('en-US');

$audioConfig = new Google_Service_Texttospeech_AudioConfig();
$audioConfig->setAudioEncoding(Google_Service_Texttospeech_AudioEncoding::MP3);
```

Everything works except the last line which is giving the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'AudioEncoding' not found in /home/******/public_html/services/remotes/post/convert-text-to-speech.php:28 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/******/public_html/services/remotes/post/convert-text-to-speech.php on line 28

Any help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be using the [Google Apis PHP client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) library which enables you to work with Google APIs such as Gmail, Drive or YouTube on your server.

You should be using the [Google Cloud PHP client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/tree/master/TextToSpeech) This client supports accessing Google Cloud Platform services.

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\AudioConfig;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\AudioEncoding;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\SynthesisInput;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\TextToSpeechClient;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\VoiceSelectionParams;

$textToSpeechClient = new TextToSpeechClient();

$input = new SynthesisInput();
$input->setText('Japan\'s national soccer team won against Colombia!');
$voice = new VoiceSelectionParams();
$voice->setLanguageCode('en-US');
$audioConfig = new AudioConfig();
$audioConfig->setAudioEncoding(AudioEncoding::MP3);

$resp = $textToSpeechClient->synthesizeSpeech($input, $voice, $audioConfig);
file_put_contents('test.mp3', $resp->getAudioContent());
```